# Form using dropdown doesn't work on Phalcon

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, phalcon

I'm using the framework Phalcon. I'm trying to create a form to get a value (an ID called "idcliente") from a table (in mysql) called cliente, which has 2 columns: "idcliente" and "nombre". With this value I want to update a field (also "idcliente") on another table called Users.

My form is this:

```
class AsignarclienteForm extends Form{

    public function initialize($entity = null, $options = null){        
        $idcliente = new Select('idcliente',[
            Cliente::find(),
            "useEmpty"  =>  true,
            "emptyText" =>  "Please select...", 
            "using" => ["idcliente", "nombre"],
            ]);
        $idcliente->setLabel('ID Cliente');
        $idcliente->addValidators(array(
            new PresenceOf(array(
                'message' => 'idcliente is required'
                ))
            ));
        $this->add($idcliente);
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
public function asignarclienteAction(){
    $auth = $this->session->get('auth');
    $permiso = $auth['active'];
    $id = $auth['id'];
    if($permiso!='A'){return $this->forward('servicios/index');}

    $form = new AsignarclienteForm;

    if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $idcliente = $this->request->getPost('idcliente');
            $sql = "UPDATE Users SET idcliente = ?0 WHERE id = ?1";
            $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($sql, array(0 => $idcliente, 1 => $id));
            return $this->forward('admin/usuarios');
        }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

And my view:

```
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{ form('admin/asignarcliente/', 'id': 'asignarclienteForm', 'onbeforesubmit': 'return false') }}
            <fieldset>
               <div class="control-group">
                {{ form.label('idcliente', ['class': 'control-label']) }}

                    <div class="controls">
                           {{ form.render('idcliente', ['class': 'form-control']) }}
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-actions">
                    {{ submit_button('Asignar', 'class': 'btn btn-primary', 'onclick': 'return SignUp.validate();') }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I got the following error in the web site:

> ID Cliente
>   Catchable fatal error: Object of class Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\OpinionZoom\cache\volt\c%%%%xampp%%htdocs%%opinionzoom%%app%%views%%admin%%asignarcliente.volt.php on line 31

Where line 31 is `{{ form.render('idcliente', ['class': 'form-control']) }}`
 on my view

I haven't found enough documentation of how to create a form with select, despite I have created a lot of forms.

If someone could help me I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks.

Comment: A question: Why do you loop over your form elements in your view? You are not using the `element` variable in your loop. Now you are just outputting your `idcliente` element x amount of times! Or was that just for debugging purposes?

Comment: @Timothy Good observation. I just copied an example I found in the Web. But you are right, in my other forms I don't have the for loop. Thank you :D Already out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element definition in your form `Asignarclienteform` is incorrect.
The first parameter of `Select` must be a string (the name of your element).
The second parameter takes the options of your select element.

```
// Select construct parameters
Select(string $name, [object | array $options], [array $attributes])
```

I moved `idcliente` out of the array into the first parameter position:

```
$idcliente = new Select('idcliente', Cliente::find(), [
    "useEmpty"  => true,
    "emptyText" => "Please select...",
    "using"     => ["idcliente", "nombre"],
]);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the error changed:
`Catchable fatal error: Object of class Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\OpinionZoom\cache\volt\c%%%%xampp%%htdocs%%opinionzoom%%app%%views%%admin%%asignarcliente.volt.php on line 28`

Comment: Are you sure your code and you error message are up to date, because it makes no sense now .. ? `form` isn't of the type `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple`. Or is it?

Comment: Yes... I find it weird also. I don't know how to see the "type" of a form. But I suspect it has something to do with `Cliente::find()`, which try to get a Resultset.

Comment: @AndrésCórdova I did